# How to make little shake after change page in UIPageViewController iOS Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swift3, uipagecontrol

How to make little **shake** *after change page* in **UIPageViewController**?
I have UIPageViewController and works correctly but i want make animate in end of changing page with *Swip right and left*.

```
self.setViewControllers(
  [getViewControllerAtIndex(idx)],
  direction: .forward,
  animated: true, completion: nil    
)
```

For realizing my intention check out **Laundrapp** app in App Store.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried this library? https://github.com/MengTo/Spring

Answer (score 1):

You should use the`UIPageViewControllerDelegate`, in particular the following method :

```
pageViewController(_:didFinishAnimating:
                     previousViewControllers:
                     transitionCompleted:)
```

Basically this method will tell you when the page controller has finished the changing page animation, once it has finished you can animate your view with the animation you like. You can also detect if the user has just scrolled a bit without changing page, inside the transitionCompleted handler.

Comment: This is good answer but how to set transition? What transition? I don't know how to set. @elio.d

Comment: what you mean by transition?

Comment: Shake animation after change page @elio.d

Comment: Since it seems that you are new to iOS I would suggest you to search more before asking, is the only way to learn :), anyway have a look at the pop framework https://github.com/facebook/pop one of the animations pop will do is the shake one

Comment: If you download Laundrapp from app store understand my intention. there is page control with animation. @elio.d